# jQuery object from jQuery selector

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

I'm new to jQuery so please advice me if I'm going in the wrong direction.

I have a function that takes as argument a "jQuery object", like this:

```
function protectImageFromRightClick(image_object) {
 // yeah ok i know this is only a dumb protection!!

    image_object.bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
        return false;
    }); 

    image_object.mousedown(function(){
        return false; // for prevent drag
    });
}
```

and I want to call it on selection. I've tried to call it with `each()`:

```
$( ".photo" ).each(function (i) {
    protect(this);
});
```

But `this` seems to refer to a DOM object that doesn't have any `.bind()` method.. I don't understand very well how I can resolve this.. any ideas?

The face is that I'm using that funciton somewhere else in the code so a solution like:

```
$('some selection').bind()
```

is not a good solution because in this way i'd write only code repetition..

Comment: however, javascript is not intended to take such functionality like protecting from right click. Note that a user can easily turn off javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call the jQuery function with a selector it does a couple tasks. First, it constructs the jQuery object. Then, it attaches the jQuery API to the newly constructed object. Then, it constructs an array of DOM elements matching the selector.

When you use `each` on a jQuery object, or when you are inside of a callback closure, the `this` keyword is going to refer to the current DOM Element that jQuery is working on.

In short,

```
$( ".photo" ).each(function (i) {
    //this == the current element with class="photo"
    //$(this) == a jquery object instanced with an 
    //           array of elements containing only the 
    //           current element with class="photo" that 
    //           each is working with
});
```

Answer (score 6):

With JQuery you have to use `$(this)` instead of the `this` keyword.

Answer (score 1):

if you iterate with each, then every iteration, the callback is called,
the argument (i) is your element.

Like in

java:

```
Vector<Integer> photo = new Vector<>();
photo.add(2); //ok very constructed..
for(int v:photo){
 // here v is your iteration variable
}
```

JS:

```
$( ".photo" ).each(function (k,v) {
    protect(v);
});
```

However, v is now pure js, not jQuery,
so you might use:

```
$( ".photo" ).each(function (k,v) {
    protect($(v));
});
```

If you wonder what k is here: k stands for key, v for value.
In an array, this might be simple, k is 0,1,2,...
but this also works on objects like `{"k1":"v1","k2":"v2"}`

Comment: Your edit made it more clear what you  were saying, but still not valid, in jQuery's [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method the first parameter is not the element, it is the index of the element in the collection. Removed down-vote assuming you will fix it ;-)

Comment: yes, right, I always forget that teh callback needs key and value -> fixed

Answer (score 0):

You could always check for a jQuery object in your function and cast it if necessary, eg

```
if (!image_object instanceof $) {
    image_object = $(image_object);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method sets `this` to the actual DOM object, you can turn that DOM object into a jQuery object by wrapping it with another `$()`

```
$(".photo").each(function () {
    protect($(this));
});
```